# ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, aiohttp

Python version: 3.11

Installing dependencies for an application by `pip install -r requirements.txt` gives the following error:

```
socket.c -o build/temp.linux-armv8l-cpython-311/aiohttp/_websocket.o
aiohttp/_websocket.c:198:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found
#include "longintrepr.h"                                   
          ^~~~~~~                        1 error generated.
error: command '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang' 
failed with exit code 1
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install
pyproject.toml-based projects
```

This error is specific to Python `3.11` version. On Python with `3.10.6` version installation goes fine.

Related question: [yarl/_quoting.c:196:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found - 1 error generated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74553366/1455694)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solution for this error: need to update `requirements.txt`.

Not working versions of modules with Python `3.11`:

```
aiohttp==3.8.1
yarl==1.4.2
frozenlist==1.3.0
```

Working versions:

```
aiohttp==3.8.2
yarl==1.8.1
frozenlist==1.3.1
```

Links to the corresponding issues with fixes:

- https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/6600
- https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl/issues/706
- https://github.com/aio-libs/frozenlist/issues/305

Answer (score 24):

aiohttp support for python 3.11/3.12 is still in beta, if you want to use that upgrade aiohttp version to 3.9.0b0

```
aiohttp==3.9.0b0
```

ref : https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/7675

Comment: I could build it using python 3.11.6. Couldn't build using 3.12 so I think this only affects 3.12.

Comment: It is Only affecting python `3.12`...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77388920/warning-c4996-py-optimizeflag-deprecated-in-3-12-aiohttp-websocket-c3042

Answer (score 5):

If you encountered some issues with downgrading you aiohttp version into 3.8.1 as me , you can go with other approach.

- Download the .whl file manually from [alpaca_trade_api-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/25/af4a06a9241d2ce7dc6870e0b0ddac0dfd07decab3ec022855eb6b90d17d/alpaca_trade_api-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl)
- Then open the .whl file with 7-zip.
- Go to alpaca_trade_api-2.3.0.dist-info\METADATA
- Open this file for edit and change the requirement in line 21

  from:

  ```
     Requires-Dist: aiohttp (==3.8.1)
  ```

  to:

  ```
     Requires-Dist: aiohttp (==3.8.4)
  ```
- Save this change.
- Go to terminal and install this wheel manually

  ```
   python -pip instal (file_location)/alpaca_trade_api-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
  ```

Worked great for me.

Answer (score 5):

Run on your windows terminal,

```
pip install aiohttp==3.9.0b0
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
pip install aiohttp==3.8.2 yarl==1.8.1 frozenlist==1.3.1 typing-extensions

pip install github==1.2.7 --no-dependencies
```

Answer (score 2):

For `Python 3.12` :

```
pip install aiohttp==3.9.0b0
```

Link to original answer:

[warning C4996: 'Py_OptimizeFlag': deprecated in 3.12 aiohttp/_websocket.c(3042): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77388920/warning-c4996-py-optimizeflag-deprecated-in-3-12-aiohttp-websocket-c3042)

Link to git : https://github.com/KillianLucas/open-interpreter/issues/581

Answer (score 1):

Always try to resolve such problems by writting on paper like by answering these questions:
What are you installing?
aiohttp
what you need correcr version of dependencies?
check what version of python you have and search which version of aiohttp is going to be compatible with your python version in my case
I have python==3.12.0 which is going to be comaptible with aiohttp==3.9.0b0

so just write pip install aiohttp==3.9.0b0