# can't install awswrangler==2.18.0 because dependency aiohttp==3.8.1 has a known issue on windows

Tags: aiohttp

during build of aiohttp==3.8.1 on windows get error

aiohttp/_websocket.c(198): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory

this is a known bug according to
[ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74550830/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-aiohttp-which-is-required-to-install-pyprojec)

trying to install awswrangler on windows 10 with python 3.11