# error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exitcode2

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-c++

so I was trying to install this package [Eur-Lex](https://pypi.org/project/eurlex/#description) on Python and had this error :

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried to find a solution on blogs or forums but it didn't work. I only have basic knowledge of Python. First of all, it was the "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required error" so I downloaded Build Tools and it works. Also tried to re-install Python after VSCode or Spyder but didn't work.
Python version : 3.8.10

Any insights ?

Comment: This is because the author of Eur-Lex did a bad job and pinned package versions. Pinning the versions is for projects, not libraries - libraries are to be used in projects, so they need to agree upon versions. The pandas version added as dependency is hard-pinned as 1.2.4 which is over 2 years old. However, there are pre-built wheels available for pandas 1.2.4 with python3.8 and I have no idea why your python isn't getting those. Are you sure it's 3.8 you're running?

Comment: Oh ok I understand, in fact I was on python3.11. I change it to python3.8 and it works, thanks !

Answer (score 4):

After fixing "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required error", I got the same issue while installing Twilio. But this works for me.

for python 3.11/12:

```
pip install aiohttp==3.9.0b0
```

And then try again,

```
pip install [package]
```

Reference:
[ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74550830/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-aiohttp-which-is-required-to-install-pyprojec)

Comment: python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel 

Try this command as well before pip install aiohttp==3.9.0b0

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. I was trying to install the dcurves package.
I tried several approaches including `pip install aiohttp==3.9.0b0` and `python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`, however neither worked.
Downgrading from python 3.12 to 3.11 solved the problem.