# Error when installing SciSpacy due to VC++ dependency

Tags: visual-c++, nlp, spacy

Error installing scispacy in Jupyter notebook

`!pip install scispacy`

Python version used is given below.
`import sys`
`print(sys.version)`

3.10.9 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Mar  1 2023, 18:18:15) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

Installed Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 before installing scispacy
[image]

Error received is:

> nmslib.cc
> C:\Users<>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i5pdmeku\nmslib_0fb91b52bae54b548ff94e9839241eb1\similarity_search\include\object.h(127):
> warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss
> of data
> C:\Users<>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i5pdmeku\nmslib_0fb91b52bae54b548ff94e9839241eb1\similarity_search\include\distcomp.h(260):
> warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'float',
> possible loss of data
> nmslib.cc(454): error C2017: illegal escape sequence
> nmslib.cc(454): error C2001: newline in constant
> nmslib.cc(459): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before 'pybind11::enum_similarity::DistType'
> nmslib.cc(459): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'pybind11::enum_similarity::DistType'
> nmslib.cc(730): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'T', possible loss of data
> with
> [
> T=int
> ]
> error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe'
> failed with exit code 2
> [end of output]
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
> problem with pip. error: legacy-install-failure
>
> × Encountered error while trying to install package. ╰─> nmslib
>
> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
> hint: See above for output from the failure.

Checked this link and tried a few solutions, none of them helped.
[error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exitcode2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76764042/error-command-c-program-files-x86-microsoft-visual-studio-2022-buildtools-v)

Please suggest the steps to resolve this error.

Comment: It probably won't help with this particular installation problem; however, you'll have a better experience going forward in modern Jupyter using the magic install commands that insure the installation occurs in the proper environment where the kernel is running. That would be `%pip install` in your case. The exclamation point doesn't insure the installation occurs in the correct environment. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands that are best practice now.