# Unable to install pip packs

Tags: python, aiohttp

I was trying to run pip install openai, but I kept getting an error saying `Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`. So I try to install aiohttp running pip install aiohttp, but got the same message‍♂️. How do I get out of this seemingly endless loop? Please help!

Comment: well, It will be helpful if you can paste more verbose messages about the build failure. Try running `pip -v install aiohttp` or such

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74550830/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-aiohttp-which-is-required-to-install-pyprojec

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74550830/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-aiohttp-which-is-required-to-install-pyprojec)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.